# Sublime 3.2.2 shortcut for skipping the next selection quick add isn't working (macOS)

Tags: sublimetext3

Yesterday I could use <kbd>⌘</kbd> `+` <kbd>k</kbd> to skip the next quick add selection. Today it's stopped working. I think the relevant line in the key bindings file is this:

```
165 { "keys": ["super+k", "super+d"], "command": "find_under_expand_skip" },
```

How can I get this important shortcut working again? There's no menu command instantiation of this function, so I can't use Apple's System Prefs for shortcut key assignment (and not sure Sublime Text would honour, some apps are flaky on that). It's for skipping the next instance of your search token when selecting duplicates of the whatever was selected when the first Quick Add was added to the selection.

Comment: Things don't stop working without a reason. Did you install any plugins? Change any key bindings? Have you tried restarting your computer? What is different between today and yesterday?

Comment: that's true, no plugins installed (don't know how). I did have the keybindings files open for a long time, the system and user (which is an empty set of bindings). The binding I noted above is still there, and I think its the correct one. I'll try a restart.

Comment: well there you go. macOS reboot and it's working again. (When I have a lot of apps open a restart actually takes me quite a while to do and restore all the apps and windows so I'm reluctant to do it sometimes.